# Google Doc Picker not centering in viewport of iframe and cant access it with scroll

Tags: macos, iframe, safari, google-api-java-client, google-picker

The Google Docs Picker works fine in all browsers within in iframe except Safari on a Mac.  It centers in the center of the iframe causing the overlay to stop everything else on the page from being clickable and scrolling in the iframe doesnt work either to get to it.  Is there a way to position the picker where the user clicked?

I noticed the top of set to a large number of the `<div class="picker picker-dialog` element.  It seems to jump to it within the iframe in the other browsers just not Safari on Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and dynamically set a height of 500px on the iframe and hid the wrapper div of the page.  This made sure the Google API picker was visible.  This made the height of the iframe smaller causing the picker to be smaller and fit the screen.

Comment: I'd check out the CSS on the iframe the containers around it using the Chrome Dev Tools. It's most likely a CSS property conflicting with the Picker causing the funky behavior on the iframe.